# Custom seekbar thumb not transparent on Lollipop API21

Tags: android, layout, android-5.0-lollipop, android-seekbar

This is my **seekbar**:

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seek1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/style_progressbar"
    android:thumb="@drawable/style_progressbar_circle"
    android:progress="20" />
```

This is **style_progressbar.xml**:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:endColor="@color/gris_hint"
                android:startColor="@color/gris_hint" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                <corners android:radius="5dp" />
                <gradient
                    android:angle="270"
                    android:endColor="@color/gris"
                    android:startColor="@color/gris" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                <corners android:radius="5dp" />
                <gradient
                    android:angle="270"
                    android:endColor="@color/gris"
                    android:startColor="@color/gris" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And this is style_progressbar_circle.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/red_scrubber_control_disabled_holo" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/red_scrubber_control_pressed_holo" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/red_scrubber_control_focused_holo" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/red_scrubber_control_normal_holo"/>
</selector>
```

This is how I see it in Lollipop

[image: Seekbar Lollipop]

This is how it should look, this is how it looks on Kitkat and lower versions.

[image: Seekbar KitKat]

Any idea? I've got some issues with layouts on Lollipop but this is the only one I can't solve for my own.

Comment: I have similar issue. I've created android bug report https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79885

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The Material seek bar has split track enabled by default. You need to turn it off.

```
<SeekBar
    ....
    android:splitTrack="false" />
```

Comment: Works like charm. Thanks. Material buttons have textAllCaps enabled by default too, the same issue.

Comment: Small tip. To override hold thumb material effect, it enough to reset background :                           android:background="@null"

Comment: get a warning that this is only used in API 21 and higher, any solution for lower versions?

Comment: @RageCompex On lower versions it's default value is false

Comment: For some reason the thumb background is drawn behind the progress bar. Does anyone know why ?

Answer (score 1):

use **android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSeekBa**r and **app:splitTrack** for all device.

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSeekBar
      app:splitTrack="false"
      android:splitTrack="false"/>
```

Comment: Declaring the `android` tag outside a v21 layout or API 21 project warns of incompatibility and using the `app` tag does not seem to work alone. Have you experienced this issue?