# Android: Invisible Seekbar Thumb Leaves "Hole" in Seekbar

Tags: android, android-layout, seekbar, android-seekbar

I want to make a seekbar thumb completely invisible. However, the following code:

```
seekBar.getThumb().mutate().setAlpha(0);
```

makes the thumb not appear, but the thumb appears to make a "hole" in its seekbar, as shown in the image below.

[image: Seekbar with split track]

How can one make a thumb invisible without it leaving a gap under it?

Comment: Kindly refer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27415918/seek-bar-thumb-not-transparent-in-android-5-0-api-21-lollipop/27540406#27540406

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is very simple.

In the seekbar's XML layout, add the following:

`android:splitTrack="false"`

Alternatively, your can programatically call:

`seekbar.setSplitTrack(false);`

The end result looks like this:

[image: Seekbar without split track]

Answer (score 0):

Use this for LOLLIPOP and newer, while in older version splitTrack=false by default

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    seekbar.setSplitTrack(false);
}
```