# Seekbar Thumb clipping

Tags: android, seekbar, android-seekbar

I'm creating a custom Seekbar with thumb.

Currently it looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2gS7.jpg

The problem:
The drawable i'm using for the thumb (an oval shape) clips over the progressbar.

My code look like this:

The Seekbar in the layout:

```
<SeekBar
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:thumb="@xml/thumb_image"
        android:progressDrawable="@xml/progress"
        android:max="100"/>
```

progress.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d"
                android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="#ff747674"
                android:angle="270"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dip" />
                <gradient
                    android:startColor="#80ffd300"
                    android:centerColor="#80ffb600"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#a0ffcb00"
                    android:angle="270"
                    />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dip" />
                <gradient
                    android:startColor="#FFD700"
                    android:centerColor="#FFB90F"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#FFA500"
                    android:angle="270"
                    />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

thumb_image.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="oval"
    android:color="@android:color/transparent">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
    <size
        android:width="30dp"
        android:height="30dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try 
**android:splitTrack="false"**
in the seek bar

For reference see this thread
[Custom seekbar thumb not transparent on Lollipop API21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26989400/custom-seekbar-with-style-errors-on-api-21)

Answer (score 5):

What worked for me was setting `android:clipChildren="false"` on the parent view.

Comment: Great solution. The slight drawback is the thumb will not respond if it is touched on the outer side of the seekBar layout (outer thumb half). This is a minor issue and this solution worked better than the many other options I tried for my situation.

Answer (score 2):

I have used `android:thumbOffset="-0dp"` and assigned custom thumb and its working fine. Implemented many solutions but they are not working perfectly because of custom thumb drawable but this one is straightforward with minimal changes.

Comment: This works, but we aware it will bring the thumb completely within the layout, so it may not line up well if you have evenly spaced out labels under the seekBar.