# i want to set seekbar setSplitTrack under lollipop

Tags: android, seekbar

i want to setSplitTrack(true) under lollipop, but i can't.

i tried set thumb's padding or margin, but it was not working.
I guess, android seekbar has stack structure, so it through all background.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Material seek bar has split track enabled by default. You need to turn it off.
This link might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/27000942/5816000

Comment: what is a material seek bar? now i'm develope under lollipop (on ICS)

Comment: Custom seekbar with material design